# How to get results with only numbers and slash

Tags: ms-access

In db I have strings like so

```
324/23/235  ->  all numbers and slashes
```

and

```
fsg/23/234  ->  NOT all numbers and slashes
```

Now when I am in desgin view currently the criteria for this column is

```
>"0"
```

how can I also add to Find just the strings that have all numbers and slashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Design View, I used this as the criteria for my text column.

```sql
Not Like "*[!0-9/]*"
```

Switching from Design to SQL View displayed this statement.

```sql
SELECT tblFoo.some_text
FROM tblFoo
WHERE (((tblFoo.some_text) Not Like "*[!0-9/]*"));
```

To understand that `Like` pattern, first consider this one ...

```sql
"*[0-9]*"
```

That matches any single character which is included in the character range 0 through 9.  To match either those digits or a slash, include a slash in the range pattern ...

```sql
"*[0-9/]*"
```

However, those are not the characters you're concerned with.  You want to target characters other than those included in the range.  So you can "negate" the range by using `!` in the first position.

```sql
"*[!0-9/]*"
```

So then `Like "*[!0-9/]*"` would give you rows whose text field string values contain any character other than 0 thru 9 or /.  But you want the opposite --- those which do not contain any other character --- so include `Not` to make the final criteria `Not Like "*[!0-9/]*"`

Comment: Great explaining!  I think i can use this the other way too.. to find just the strings that have letters and numbers only.. cheers

Answer (score 1):

The Replace function will remove the slashes and replace with and empty space.  IsNumeric will return a Boolean = True if the remaining characters can be converted successfully to an number.

```
Select * from [TableWithStrings] as t
where IsNumeric(Replace(t.[FieldWithTheseStrings], "/", ""))=True;
```

These functions could be used in code as well as your view.

Comment: I am not sure where to put this.. As i am in the Desgin view for a Query in Access.  I was hopeing there was a way i could add something to the Criteria for this field

Comment: `IsNumeric("-2.3")` returns `True` and so does `IsNumeric("2e2")`. But OP indicated he is interested in only `0-9` and `/`.